# Asp.Net GridView order data bound columns before declarative ones

Tags: asp.net, gridview, xmldatasource

I have a gridview that is databound to a XmlDataSource. I also want to add a `<columns>` section with a buttonfield at the **end** of the gridview. When I add a columns section it prepends it (before xml columns). How could I order

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    datafile="some.xml" TransformFile="some.xslt" />
<asp:GridView ID="linksGrid" runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="xmlDataSource1" 
  CssClass="adminGrid" 
  AllowPaging="True" 
  AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="WhiteSmoke">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField runat="server" ButtonType="Button" Text="details" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

this produces a table like this:
[image]

I want the order to be reversed: Title, Url, Button column

bones question, how could I space the columns so the modify button has no weight (fits to column) and the remaining cells to get even space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will surely help you.

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField > 
                <FooterTemplate >
                    <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me"/>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>    
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick was

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false .. />
```

I could simply use a asp:BoundField in my < columns > section to specify the order.

I will leave this open a bit if someone can provide an answer on how to CSS format individual columns.